# Continously getting WhiteLabel Error Page - Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, jsp, spring-mvc

Hey i have a problem with viewing a jsp file in a simple spring boot app.

Here are my project files:

pom.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.sample</groupId>
<artifactId>boot-sample</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.sample;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;


@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String home(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

home.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>text</h2>
</body>

</html>
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3wuK.png)

I figured out that it may be something with file structure or prefix path in application.properties, still haven't found an answer though.

Comment: "i have a problem with viewing a jsp file" - What's the problem? Please include a specific question.

Comment: are you building your `jar` or `war`?

Comment: Here is a simple example: https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/

Comment: @avojak i meant the whitelabel error page, but i managed to solve it myself. In pom.xml in the tomcat-embed-jasper dependency i had a  <scope>provided</scope> tag. I removed it and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From Spring boot Documentation:**

> JSPs should be avoided if possible, there are several known
>   limitations when using them with embedded servlet containers.

You can take further reading here:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-template-engines

Comment: As i mentionned in a comment section above it works now, but i swapped to thymeleaf templates anyway. Thanks fr your answer.

Comment: Was it helpful? @sidzej

Comment: ye, it's pretty convenient